# autocomplete not ful complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I have written an autocomplete function. 
When I click on #input3 it starts to generate what I have typed.

Example: "apple" I type "app" and I click to select "apple". What I select should be sent to the src and updated in #input2.

Problem: What is sent to the src is what I have typed and not what I have selected. Why?

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            fillin:true,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term,
                c3 : $("#input3").val()
                },
            success: function(data){
                response(data)
                }
            });
        },
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 300
    })
.change(function(request2, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: src,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term : request2.term,
            c1 : "search",
            c3: $("#input3").val()
            },
        success: function(data){
            $("#input2").val(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: bind custom event on the input2, then trigger it by select: and change event of autocomplete.

Comment: How do I trigger it by select?

Comment: Before asking another question, go back and select an answer to one of the _7_ open questions you have.

Comment: Opps sorry, didn't know I had to Answer them.

Comment: Arhh now I get it, I have to click on the tick!

Comment: execute select: as Kyokasuigetsu show for change, trigger event by trigger method of jquery;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it. I add the cod after .autocomplete

```
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#txtBufferTwo").val(ui.item.value);
            event.preventDefault();
            },
```

Follow by a hidden field.

What I did was once selection was click, the value is assign to the hidden field and submit the value of the hidden field.
If there is any better methods feel free to post here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event in jquery ui autocomplete:

```
 $("#your_input_id").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            change: function(){
            console.log($(this).val());//selected value
            }
 });
```

Comment: I added the code right before 'minLength: 0,' It doesn't respond.